Could not start MCP server for Brave Search in Computer Use and Claude Desktop
I am setting up Computer use (beta) for Anthropic in Windows PoweShell (administrator). But when I want to connect to MCP server for Brave Search in Claude desktop app, I received this error:
Could not start MCP server brave-search: Error: spawn npx ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npx',
  path: 'npx',
  spawnargs: [Array]

I have installed node.js earlier.

I have also setup the token for Brave Search in claude_desktop_config.json as below

{
  "mcpServers": {
    "brave-search": {
      "command": "npx",
      "args": [
        "-y",
        "@modelcontextprotocol/server-brave-search"
      ],
      "env": {
        "BRAVE_API_KEY": "NOT SHOWING MY KEY HERE"
      }
    }
  }
}


Any tips?
Best,

I use the setting like:
{
"mcpServers": {
    "brave-search": {
        "command": "C:\\the\\path\\of\\node",
        "args": [
            "-e",
            "require('child_process').execSync('npx -y @modelcontextprotocol/server-brave-search', {stdio: 'inherit'})"
        ],
        "env": {
            "BRAVE_API_KEY": "apikey"
        }
    }
}
}

the "npx" does not work in windows.

Here is another example if you installed node.js in the program files:
{
"mcpServers": {
  "brave-search": {
    "command": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
    "args": [
       "C:\\{LOCATION TO NPM} \\npm\\node_modules\\@modelcontextprotocol\\server-brave-search\\dist\\index.js"
    ],

    "env": {
      "BRAVE_API_KEY": "{YOUR BRAVE API KEY}"
    }
  }
}
}


TLDR: PATH is not the same when spawning from a desktop app; put the absolute path of the executable in the config to skip path resolution.
The Claude desktop app is a GUI app, so the spawn command inherits the PATH of a GUI app, which is not the same as PATH in the terminal. The easiest solution is to put the absolute path of the executable in the config so you don't have to rely on the app PATH.
Now for the deep dive...
Could not start MCP server brave-search: Error: spawn npx ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npx',
  path: 'npx',
  spawnargs: [Array]

This error means that npx wasn't found in the spawn PATH, so the client couldn't run the command to start the MPC server. The PATH of a spawned Node process inherits from the parent app and may be different from your shell. It's common for commands that work in the terminal not to work when run as a spawned Node child process.
Try something like this:
{
  "mcpServers": {
    "brave-search": {
      "command": "C:\\path\\to\\node\\node.exe",
      "args": [
        "C:\\path\\to\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js",
        "-y",
        "@modelcontextprotocol/server-brave-search"
      ],
      "env": {
        "BRAVE_API_KEY": "apikey"
      }
    }
  }
}

NPX is weird on Windows, so YMMV with this solution, but different PATH variables is the reason it works in the terminal but not when Claude tries to spawn the server.
